# i am trying to download googles sample code Type a Number Challenge?

Tags: android

I am new to git hub and i was wondering how I could download the whole project. HERE is the page github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples
Im new to all of this so any help is aprecciated and thanks so much.

Comment: click here -> https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the project as a zip file from [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/archive/master.zip)

There is button for it: [image]